# Naming general objects in more than 3 dimensions

Tags: geometry, terminology

In a paper I am writing, I need to talk about a general "object" formed by the points of a connected set in an $n$-dimensional euclidean space. I have found some suggestion [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Four-DimensionalGeometry.html), but none fit my needs. The "object" I am concerned with do not have any specific shape restriction : I cannot speak of $n$-polytope, $n$-spheres, etc. I cannot either use $n$-curve or hypercurve  as these objects I am talking about could be "thick". So I would really need some general terminology.

1) Do you know of terminology in use? What is important to me is to convey the idea that the object lies in a multidimensional space and could be "thick".

I have googled "hypershape", "hyperobject", $n-object" and "n-shape" but these do not seem to be in use.

2) I am tempted to use either "hyperobject" or "$n$-object". Do you think this would be understood?

Comment: Do the points form a connected region (or some reasonable union of connected components)?  Or are they a *point cloud?*

Comment: They do form a connected region. I'll edit the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Do they firm a submanifold? Or a sun manifold with boundary?

Comment: Is the dimension essential to what is being discussed?  I would just call it an "$n$-dimensional region" or just a "connected region in $\Bbb{R}^n$".

Comment: (I'm asking these questions because to me it seems that we give names to things in mathematics in order to suggest certain intuitive ideas to the reader.  What aspects of this set are important?)

Comment: @ studiosus : sorry, I do not know enough about manifolds to answer you question.

Comment: @ Sammy Black : the exact number of dimensions itself is not essential. What is essential is to convey the idea that the object could be "thick", and lies in a multidimensional space. Let me edit the question again to make this clearer. I like the "regional" terminology, thanks for suggesting it. Maybe you could consider making this an answer?

Comment: "[Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_object)" is a little too broad; depending on context it could refer to anything. I second Sammy's suggestion of just calling it a region in $n$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments constitute a good answer:

> We give names to things in mathematics in order to suggest certain intuitive ideas to the reader. What aspects of this set are important? [...] I would just call it an "n-dimensional region" or just a "connected region in $\mathbb{R}^N$ (Sammy Black)

@ Sammy Black : the exact number of dimensions itself is not essential. What is essential is to convey the idea that the object could be "thick", and lies in a multidimensional space. Let me edit the question again to make this clearer. (OP)

> "[Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_object)" is a little too broad; depending on context it could refer to anything. I second Sammy's suggestion of just calling it a region in n-dimensional space. (Rahul Narain)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions. You should ask yourself, how is this object given to you: Is it the image of a map? Is is given as a solution of a system of equations? Equations and inequalities? Strict or non-strict inequalities? Are the functions involved in the definition of your object continuous? Differentiable? Polynomial? Piecewise-linear?

Depending on answers to these questions, you might describe your objects better than just "connected regions". For instance, if your objects are given by systems of polynomial equations and inequalities of the form
$$
f_j(x_1,...,x_n)=a_j, \quad g_k(x_1,...,x_n)\le b_k
$$
then they would be called *semialgebraic subsets* of $R^n$. Moreover, if $a_j$'s and $b_k$ are "generic" in suitable sense (which I can make precise if needed), then your objects, in addition, would be smooth manifolds (with boundary).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize I should have been much more precise in describing the object in the question. The object is actually defined by the equivalent-class of a preorder of some multidimensional space for some element of this space.

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden: This suggests that the object is likely to be a union of convex solids. However, without knowing more details about it, I cannot tell.